# Selenium Python загрузка файла на сервер

Tags: python, selenium, автоматизация

Пишу автоматизацию входа на сайт, среди шагов которой есть необходимость загрузки файла (цифровой подписи), нахожу нужный элемент, когда использую click() всё нормально, открывается окно для выбора файла который нужно загрузить, но когда пытаюсь использовать метод send_keys() на этот-же элемент, то ни чего не получается ошибка (Message: element not interactable). В разметке HTML  в которой идёт поиск, нет тегов типа "input type=file", вместо этого мой элемент содержит такую строку JavaScript

```
<span class="jss525" onclick="document.getElementById('PKeyFileInput').click();">оберіть його на своєму носієві</span>
```

Возможно нужно использовать execute_script, но Я не пойму как?

```
press_button_select_key = browser.find_element(By.ID, "PKeyFileName").click() - находит и открывает 
press_button_select_key = browser.find_element(By.ID, "PKeyFileName").send_keys("D:/Path_to_file") - не работает
```

Comment: `send_keys` нужно использовать на input-е с `type="file"`. Из вопроса непонятно  как между собой соотносятся элементы с `id=PKeyFileInput` и `id=PKeyFileName`.

Comment: Чисто ради спортивного интереса, у этого сайта API есть?

Comment: Как проверить? Подскажите.

Answer (score 0):

Всё в порядке, работает, Я не правильно определял ID элемента, метод send_keys работает на этом тэге.